# Android HTTP Post upload image in webview session

Tags: android, cookies, webview, http-headers, http-post

I've been reading for more than three days about this and my head is totally messed up. I saw too much code.. Plaase help! 
I have an application with a webview. In this webview I am logged in an account. So this means that when I get to the upload part I must use the webview session. I didn't understand very clear how to work with cookies. Also in the uploader I must set the Content-type and the Content-Disposition.
So my question is: Would you give me an example all this things? Getting the cookies, setting them to the http post request and setting the cookies so I can send the image. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why you need the webview for? Just look at the HttpPost, HttpURLConnection classes and you are all done.

Comment: The webview is a part of the application. I have a task to do and it includes the webview. In the webview I click a button and it starts a new activity where I sand an image.